# Searching a text file and displaying the matching lines

Tags: python

The loop does not find the second search phrase after it has successfully located and printed the lines from the text file. The second time the user is prompted for the search phrase it is not locating it and instead prints `"Please try again"`.

```
searchfile = open("Test.txt", "r")
content = searchfile.readlines()
lines = len(content)

while lines>0:
    phrase = raw_input('Please enter search word ')
    for line in content:
        if phrase in line:
            print (line)
            found = True

    else:
        print 'Please try again'
        break

searchfile.close()
```

Comment: Put your code here and don't give a link to a picture of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `break` out of your code.

```
phrase // word you are searching for...
with open("Test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if phrase in line:
            print (line)
```

This will print all lines with a match.

Comment: Once you found one match it will exit the for loop and stop further search matching.

Comment: @PythonHelp if you want to do that to more than a word, you can wrap this in a function. And outside in a loop ask for user input and call the function with that input.

Comment: sorry, it is not searching for the next term, how do I get it to do this?

Comment: @PythonHelp what is the problem ? what is not searching for next term ?

Comment: Once it has displayed the matching lines for the first search term, when the second term is entered, it says try again

Comment: @PythonHelp I can't help you without seeing the code. Perhaps start another question or edit this one.

Comment: it is the same code, if you generate a text file with some repeated keywords, and run this code, you will see that the search is performed for the first search phrase and returns the matching line from the text file but it will not find the next search phrase although it exists in the file

Comment: @PythonHelp can you edit your current question. Write EDIT: and under it add your code ? (don't delete the existing code)